# Save the Results From For Loop When There Is an Error R

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's say I have this for loop

```
results<-c()
score<-c(19,14,13,9,"A",15)
for(index in 1:length(score)){
 results[index]<- index + score[index]
}
```

how can I return the results before the error happen?

```
> results
[1] 20 16 16 13
```

Can I stop the loop while its working and return results even didn't finish all the index?

Comment: Why do you think that the result will be `[1] 20 16 16 13`? At the first index itself you have `"19"` and not numeric `19`, so the error occurs at first index rather than at index 5. R automatically converts all values to character type due to presence of `"A"`. Please check the `class(score)` first.

Comment: As @TUSHAr rightly said, `score` is already character because of presence of `"A"`, you need to convert it to numeric first.  `as.numeric(score) + seq_along(score)` could be helpful. For `"A"`, it would just return `NA`.

Comment: you are right its "19" but this is just scenario i want to explain my problem with

Comment: Are you sure that there is still a problem with returning intermediate results if you fix the error in your question? R should keep the intermediate results when the loop throws an error partway through.

Comment: Are there any way to tell r if something wrong happens to the loop return whatever you calculate and saved in  results?

Answer (score 2):

You can try capturing the warning or error like this using tryCatch. As soon as a condition occurs, the loop will be stopped and control is transferred to corresponding `warning` or `error` functions.

```
results<-c()
score<-c(19,14,13,9,"A",15)
tryCatch(expr = {
    for(index in 1:length(score)){
        results[index]<- index + as.numeric(score[index])
}
},warning=function(w){print(w)},
error=function(e){print(e)},
finally = results)

<simpleWarning in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): NAs introduced by coercion>

> results
#[1] 20 16 16 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here comes break flow control handy:

```
results<-c()
score<-c(19,14,13,9,"A",15)
for(index in 1:length(score)){
  if(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(score[index])))){
    break
  }
  results[index]<- index + as.numeric(score[index])
}

results
#[1] 20 16 16 13
```